# Why does p not satisfy the interface for c (line 106)?

Tags: go, inheritance, interface, tree, composition

```
import "fmt"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
type NodeType uint

const (
    COMMAND NodeType = iota
    PROPERTY
    )

type Node interface {
    setChildren(...*Node)
    getChildren() []*Node
    setParent(*Node)
    getParent() *Node
    getFlavor() NodeType
    getValue() string
}



// Command Node

type CommandNode struct {
    self *Node
    parent *Node
    children []*Node
    command string
    level int
    partial, complete bool
}


func (cn *CommandNode) setChildren(child ...*Node) {
    for _,v := range child {
        cn.children = append(cn.children,v)
    }
}

func (cn *CommandNode) getChildren() []*Node {
    return cn.children
}

func (cn *CommandNode) setParent(parent *Node) {
    cn.parent = parent
}

func (cn *CommandNode) getParent() *Node {
    return cn.parent
}

func (cn *CommandNode) getFlavor() NodeType {
    return COMMAND
}

func (cn *CommandNode) getValue() string {
    return cn.command
}

// Property Node

type PropertyNode struct {
    self *Node
    parent *Node
    children []*Node
    property string
    level int
    partial, complete bool
}


func (pn *PropertyNode) setChildren(child ...*Node) {
    for _,v := range child {
        pn.children = append(pn.children,v)
    }
}

func (pn *PropertyNode) getChildren() []*Node {
    return pn.children
}

func (pn *PropertyNode) setParent(parent *Node) {
    pn.parent = parent
}

func (pn *PropertyNode) getParent() *Node {
    return pn.parent
}

func (pn *PropertyNode) getFlavor() NodeType {
    return PROPERTY
}

func (pn *PropertyNode) getValue() string {
    return pn.property
}


func main() {
c := CommandNode{
    command:  "command",
}

p := PropertyNode{
    property: "data 1, data 2, data 3",
}

c.setChildren(&p)

x := c.getChildren()

for k,v := range x {
    fmt.Printf("x[%d] is %v\n",k,v)
}



}
```

This line -> `c.setChildren(p)` fails at compilation, saying that I can't use a PropertyNode as *Node, I was under the impression that PropertyNode has the interface methods as defined on the Node interface, I could use them interchangeably?

My end goal is to be able to have a tree of nodes (different types of nodes) that use the same methods for tree-traversal.. I thought I could use interfaces on different node types to accomplish this.

Comment: The method signatures do not match. You're also using `*Node` in a lot of places, when a pointer to an interface is almost never what you want.

Comment: you're correct, I ended up matching the function signatures then had to remove all the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyNode` does not implement `Node` because `setChildren` is declared in the interface as `setChildren(...*Node)`, but implementation has `setChildren(*Node)`.

Comment: Hmmn, I changed it to reflect the variadic in the interface, but still have the same issue: 

```

Comment: What is the complete error? It should tell you what's missing.